# When protected protects too much

Tags: c++, inheritance, protected

This is about "protected", which is explained as: "When a class inherits another one, the members of the derived class can access the protected members inherited from the base class." However, look at this code:

```
class Base {
public:
  Base( int m ) : member(m){}
protected:
  int member;
};

class Derived : public Base { // one of several subclasses
public:
  Derived( int m ) : Base(m), value(10) {}
  int diff( Base x ){
    return value - x.member;
  }
private:
  int value;
};
```

Derived accesses "x.member", which is protected in its Base class, right? But the compiler flags an error, "Base::member is protected". And, after mulling this over for a minute, I had to agree with the compiler.

And here comes the question: *How do I make this work, with a minimum loss of information hiding?*

1. Clearly, making "member" public compiles, but it's against the original intent.
2. Using the "friend" mechanism in Base to let subclasses access "member" (and everything else that's private and protected) is even worse (apart from the dumb binding of a superclass to its own subclasses - a maintenance nightmare).
3. In the simple example, a public int getMember(){ return member; } would be acceptable. But if member's type is a X*, the best you can do is a public **const** X* getMember(){...}.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Just define `int diff( Derived x )`, or not?

Comment: Also when reading your point 1 and 3, one can conclude that the protection-of-member-sense is that it may be read but not changed. So a get method would do it well. Also a public const-reference or const-pointer-to-const to member, which is initialized in constructor list of Base would be possible. Your point 3 and "the best you can do ... **const** X*" depends on what you want: a get method returns value anyway. So you couldn't change the value of member of type X* with `X* get()`. Only what it points to.

Comment: What about making a function `int diff(Derived d, Base b)` and make this function a `friend` of both classes?

Comment: @mb84 diff used type Base in order to make it useful for all possible subtypes. (Perhaps Base* would make the intent clearer, but it's not polymorphism I'm after.) - My original situation had member's type as char*, and I disliked returning this pointer, even as a const char*.

Comment: @rozina OK, if there aren't too many places where this kind of access is necessary.

Comment: May I ask why you dislike returning a `const char*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a static protected accessor:

```
class Base {
public:
  Base( int m ) : member(m){}
private:
  int member;
protected:
  static int GetMember(const Base &b)
  { return b.member; }
};

class Derived : public Base { // one of several subclasses
public:
  Derived( int m ) : Base(m), value(10) {}
  int diff( Base &x ){ //beware of your slicing!
    return value - GetMember(x);
  }
private:
  int value;
};
```

Now let me add my idea of why C++ access control works this way...

Access control in C++ is not about *information hiding*. It is about *encapsulation*. That is, plainly speaking, you filter out the access to any member that can break the class if used incorrectly.

In an ideal class

- public members cannot be used to break the object.
- private members know what they are doing.

As you see, in my scheme there is little place for protected members:

- protected members are used to implement the inheritance interface, if any.

And even less place for protected member variables.

So make your variable private, and write a protected accessor. The accessor must be static to be able to be used from the derived object.

Comment: "variables do not define a proper interface": bad news for `std::pair` ;-) Of course, it's not intended as a base class, so all I'm really quibbling over is whether you should have said "variables do not define a proper inherited interface" or some such.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Hmmm, dad choice of words. Of course they can be part of an interface. What I meant is that an interface made of variables is unlimited, so you cannot force an invariant on them. If that is what you want go public; if not, go private; but protected variables make little sense. Of course, there are cases where they may be useful (I've used them), but not many.

Comment: Agreed, `pair` is special because by definition its two members are independent. No class invariant relates them.

Comment: @rodrigo "one may think of information hiding as being the principle and encapsulation being the technique" as wikipedia has it, and I'm inclined to agree with the author. Ultimately mean the same thing. - I also dislike protected and use it as sparingly as possible. - I like the idea of the static getter, although, hmm,...

Answer (score 3):

You can keep the protected attributes, add the getter functions as you mentioned. As for a protected pointer attribute, the getter would make sure that `int` (or a const ref for a large object) is returned and you can do the difference in a function template that takes Derived and Base arguments then (getters give you the values for the calculation).

Protecting data attributes allows direct access to the protected attribute within the derived class. What you tried is to access a private attribute of another object. This part of your code:

```
int diff( Base x ){
    return value - x.member;
  }
```

would be equivalent to writing this in `main`:

```
Base x; 
cout << x.member << endl;
```

Here is an example of how to solve the problem using the option 3 you suggested yourself, with a derived class `PointerDerived` that is using pointers for the storage:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
  Base( int m ) : member(m){}

  int getMember() const
  {
      return member; 
  }

protected:
  int member;
};

class Derived : public Base { // one of several subclasses
public:
  Derived( int m ) : Base(m), value(10) {}

  int getValue() const
  {
      std::cout << "protected = " << member << std::endl;
      return value; 
  }

private:
  int value;
};

class PointerDerived : public Base { // one of several subclasses
public:

  PointerDerived( int m ) : Base(m), value(new int (10)) {}

  int getValue() const
  {
      std::cout << "protected = " << member << std::endl;
      return *value; 
  }

  ~PointerDerived()
  {
      delete value; 
      value = nullptr;  
  }

private:
  int* value;
};

template<typename Derived, typename Base>
int diff(const Derived& d, const Base& b)
{
    return d.getValue() - b.getMember(); 
}

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    PointerDerived p(23); 
    Base q(1);

    cout << diff(p, q) << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Compile the program with `-std=c++11` because of the nullptr, or change it to `NULL`.

You make the `diff` a function template, so that you don't have to overload it for each and every derived class, and you let the derived class handle the storage and access to it as does for example `PointerDerived`.

Comment: Some of this code answers a question that was not being asked. I'm not really sure that will help even the OP, let alone anyone else who would try to find the answer to the original question.

Comment: I just added the int* because the OP asked about having X* as a protected data member. Getters are there because the OP said that it would be acceptable for a simple example. diff is a function because the getters make sure that the PointerDerived returns an int - for this simple example. Does that make sense?